# fetch document version in nuxeo

Tags: version, nuxeo

Is there a way to get all versions and related File of single document
Suppose that I have published document 'abcd' with version 1.0. Then later, I modify the document and publish it with 1.5 and i want both version in java so is ther any possible way to get all documents with diffrent version in nuxeo.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [CoreSession.getVersions](http://community.nuxeo.com/api/nuxeo/7.10/javadoc/org/nuxeo/ecm/core/api/CoreSession.html#getVersions-org.nuxeo.ecm.core.api.DocumentRef-) will do that for you. There are also variants of this API that returns just document references or a bit more information related to each version. You should peruse the `CoreSession` API to know more.

Comment: but how we can get core session in java.i am not able to get core session